# How to get rid of boost library exports in final executable

Tags: boost, dllexport

I'm compiling an executable and I use boost libraries inside that executable.
no matter if i use static linking or dynami linking of boost with "BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK" , my final executable contains exports from the boost library.

[image]

which is very undesirable.

Update: My compiler is Visual studio 2019 and I'm compiling for x86 platform. however it's the same for x64 as well.

Comment: you should mention your platform and compiler

Comment: @sehe i just did.